# Sequence Diagram: Interactions with resources (DB, Network, Caches, etc)

Tags: resources, uml, diagram, modeling, sequence-diagram

I am currently making a behavior assessment of different software modules regarding access to DB, Network, amount of memory allocations, etc.

The main goal is to pick a main use case( let's say system initialization) and recognize the modules that are:

- Unnecessarily accessing DB.
- Creating too many caches for same data.
- Making too many allocations (or too big) at once.
- Spawning many threads,
- Network access

By assessing those, I could have an overview of the modules that need to be reworked in order to improve performance, delete redundant DB accesses, avoid CPU usage peaks, etc.

I found the sequence diagram a good candidate to represent the use cases behavior, but I am not sure how to depict their interaction with the above mentioned activities.

I could do something like shown in this picture, but that is an "invention" of tagging functions with colors. I not sure if it is too simplistic or childish (too many colors?).

[image]
I wonder if there is any specific UML diagram to represent these kind of interactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SDs is probably the most appropriate approach here. You might consider timing diagrams in certain cases if you need to present timing constraints. However, SDs already have a way to show timing constraints which is quite powerful.

You should adorn your diagram with a comment telling that the length of the colored self-calls represent percentage of use or something like that (or just adding a title telling this). Using colors is perfect by the way.

As a side note: (the colored) self-calls are shown with a self-pointing arrow like this

[image]

but I'd guess your picture can be understood by anyone and you can see that as nitpicking. And most likely they are not real self-calls but just indicators. So that's fine too.

**tl;dr** Whatever transports the message is appropriate.